# Initialize collection objects in random order using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using spring, with hibernate and Mysql db.
  I have Question object, which has Set of Answer objects.

My question.hbm.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.gamesapp.model.Question" table="question" >
         <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="questionId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="question_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="description" length="500" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="difficultyLevel" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="difficulty_level" length="6" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="isMixer" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="is_mixer" length="5" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="status" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="status" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="answers"  inverse="true"   >
         <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <key>
                <column name="question_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.gamesapp.model.Answer" />
        </set>

        <set name="questionAnswerUsers"  inverse="true" >
         <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <key>
                <column name="question_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.gamesapp.model.QuestionAnswerUser" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My answer.hbm.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.gamesapp.model.Answer" table="answer" >
       <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="answerId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="answer_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="question" class="com.gamesapp.model.Question" fetch="select">
            <column name="question_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="description" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dragPosition" type="java.lang.Short">
            <column name="drag_position" />
        </property>
        <property name="orderSequence" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="order_sequence" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="isAnswer" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="is_answer" length="5" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="askPercentage" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="ask_percentage"  not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="questionAnswerUsers"  inverse="true">
           <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <key>
                <column name="answer_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.gamesapp.model.QuestionAnswerUser" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now my problem is that, I want to fetch List of Question in random order. 
  And for every Question object I want to eager fetch set of answer using hibernate criteria and answer set should also initialize randomly.

For example say Question object questionOne has a set of answer having four Answer object.say ans1, ans2, ans3 and ans4. Now first time I fetch questionOne, answer set should be initialize as answer={ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4}second time I fetch questionOne object I should get answer set as answer={ans4,ans2,ans3,ans1}.

List of Question should come randomly initialize.
  Ever Question's Answer set should be fetched eagrly using hibernate criteria, whost item should come shuffled every time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `Collections.shuffle()` to get a shuffled list:

```
List<Question> questions = em.createQuery(...).getResultList();
Collections.shuffle(questions);
```

And in the Question entity:

```
public List<Answer> getShuffledAnswers() {
    List<Answer> result = new ArrayList<Answer>(this.answers);
    Collections.shuffle(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply JB Nizet. But the problem is that I want to initialize set of answer, randomly initialize by Hibernate not by using java. And if I use above approach I have to define another collection in Question class.

Comment: Here is the criteria.                                                                                     try {
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Question.class)
.setFetchMode("answers", FetchMode.JOIN)     .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=1 group by question_id order by RAND() "))

   
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
   re.printStackTrace();
   log.debug(re);
   return null;
  }

Comment: If Set does not work for this approach, please suggest me for List<Answer>.                                                         Thanks

Comment: No, you don't have to add another collection to Question. You just need to add this 3-line method above, which transforms the set of answers into a shuffled list of answers.